# count blank lines for some position in a file

Tags: bash, shell

I am using bash version 4.1.2

I have a file and I have to ensure the column position 10-20 are all blanks in the file.

So I use this method:

```
COUNTER=` cut -c10-20 MY_FILE | tr -d ' ' | grep -v '^$' | wc -l `
if [[ $COUNTER -gt 0 ]]
then
     echo There is some non-blank char in position 10-20
fi
```

This method does not work.
The grep command give the message: `Binary file (standard input) matches`

even when they are all blanks in position 10-20 for the whole file.
So, this make the COUNTER becomes 1 (actually, it should be 0)

I have try to use `grep --text -v '^$'`
This does not work, the succeeding `wc -l` will then give the total number of lines in the file.

Any Help ?

Alvin SIU

Comment: Sorry guys, I finally find out the cause.  There are many NULL char in each line of MY_FILE.  Maybe these NULL char make the grep command behaves strangely. When I use ANOTHER_FILE which does not contain NULL char, the above statement runs very smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

try the below,

```
COUNTER=` cut -c10-20 filename.txt| tr -d ' ' | grep -v '^$' | wc -l `
if [ $COUNTER -gt 0 ];then
 echo 'There is some non-blank char in position 10-20'
fi
```

Note: correct the mistake in calling the variable inside the IF statement and the filename as ShravanYadav has mentioned

Answer (score 0):

MY_FILE you are using is filename or variable name. you should use ${MY_FILE}
if MY_FILE is variable

```
COUNTER=` cut -c10-20 ${MY_FILE} | tr -d ' ' | grep -v '^$' | wc -l `
```